# Redirect /123/POST to just /POST in wordpress using .htaccess Rewrite Rules

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I have a website running wordpress with some good amount of posts.

For a specific reason, i setup my wordpress permalinks structure to `/%post_id%/%postname%/`

Now i want change my permalink structure to `/%postname%/` for supporting a plugin `Category Subdomain Pro`

When i change the change the permalink structure, new links are working but i am getting a 404 error for old urls.

So, i am thinking about redirecting old urls to new urls.

If you know anything about this, please share something and help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for delay, Check this out... Before # BEGIN WordPress in .htaccess file put this code...

```
Redirect 301 /post_id/postname/ http://example.com/postname/
```

just replace post_id,postname to your website posts id and post name. Replace example.com with your website name and postname with your postname.

replace for every single post

or you can use plugin [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)

Comment: sorry for not explaining clearly,
new links are working but i am getting a 404 error for old urls.
Because of that i will loose all search engine traffic.